# How to remove white outline from label text in Apache E Charts Bar Chart

Tags: apache-echarts

I have a Bar Chart made with Apache E Charts. For the label values, there is a white outline bordering the text. I have tried adjusting several options to try and get rid of it, but have had no luck. What is the option that would allow me to get rid of this white outline and just show black text?

[image: Bar Chart]

Full options code per request:

```
const option = useMemo(() => {
if (data) {
  return {
    dataset: {
      source: data,
    },
    textStyle: {
      fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
    },
    title: {
      text: "AR Aging",
      left: "left",
      textStyle: {
        fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
      },
    },
    tooltip: {
      trigger: "axis",
      axisPointer: {
        type: "shadow",
      },
    },
    color: ["#ff4242", "#ff4242", "#FFA500", "#fddc20", "#209c05"],
    grid: { containLabel: true, height: "70%" },
    xAxis: {
      name: "Amount",
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: (params) => formatMoney(params),
      },
    },
    yAxis: { name: "Period", type: "category" },
    series: [
      {
        type: "bar",
        colorBy: "data",
        legendHoverLink: true,
        label: {
          show: true,
          formatter: (params) => formatMoney(params.value[0]),
        },
        labelLayout(params) {
          return {
            x: params.rect.x + 10,
            y: params.rect.y + params.rect.height / 2,
            verticalAlign: "middle",
            align: "left",
          };
        },
        encode: {
          x: "Amount",
          y: "Period",
        },
      },
    ],
  };
}
}, [data]);
```

formatMoney() takes a number and returns a formatted currency string. And my data object is something like this:

```
const data = [
      ["Amount", "Period"],
      [100000, "180+"],
      [90000, "91-180"],
      [80000, "61-90"],
      [70000, "31-60"],
      [60000, "0-30"],
    ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

What you found is very interesting, I think it's a bug or at least a missing feature in echarts - setting, in a bar chart, the `labelLayout` `x` or `y` properties messes with the coloring of the label. The cause for that is the fact that echarts (in zrender's function [`Element#updateInnerText`](https://github.com/ecomfe/zrender/blob/master/src/Element.ts#L582)) doesn't know that the `label` `isInside`. So, if you set `x` or `y`, it appears that it will use coloring for labels that are placed outside of the bar, on the background of the chart itself.

Let's look at a couple of possible solutions:

1. avoid setting `x` and `y` in `labelLayout`, but use `dx` and `dy` instead. The formula used in the original code to set the label 10px from the left margin of the bar was: 
   `x: params.rect.x + 10`;
    the equivalent `dx` setting (taking into account that the default position is at the center of the `params.rect` is: 
   `dx: -params.rect.width/2 + 10`.

   Note the animation of the labels in this case. That can of course be disabled by disabling the animation of the series (`series[].animation: false`).
2. set an explicit `backgroundColor: transparent` in the `label` option. Note that `transparent` is the default value for label, but the result is not exactly the default behavior of inside label coloring - text color is black or white depending on the color of the bar.

   Note that for this second solution, one may as well set explicitly the `color` of the label, which precludes the need to set the `backgroundColor`. So one may juts use `color: black` instead of `backgroundColor: transparent`.

In the snippet below the same bars are shown thrice: for the topmost one, the first solution (use `dx` instead of `x`) and the default coloring, for the second one the `backgroundColor: transparent` solution, and for the third one, the original version with the undesired outline.

```js
const data = [
  ["Amount", "Period"],
  [100000, "180+"],
  [80000, "61-90"],
  [70000, "31-60"],
  [60000, "0-30"]
];

const option = {
  dataset: {
    source: data
  },
  color: ["#ff4242", "#FFA500", "#fddc20", "#209c05"],
  xAxis: {
    name: "Amount",
  },
  yAxis: {
    name: "Period",
    type: "category"
  },
  series: [{ // solution 1: replace x by dx
      type: "bar",
      colorBy: "data",
      label: {
        show: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      labelLayout(params) {
        return {
          dx: -params.rect.width / 2 + 10,
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          align: "left"
        };
      },
      encode: {
        x: "Amount",
        y: "Period"
      }
    },
    { // solution 2: backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      type: "bar",
      colorBy: "data",
      label: {
        show: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        // or:
        // color: 'black'
      },
      labelLayout(params) {
        return {
          x: params.rect.x + 10,
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          align: "left"
        };
      },
      encode: {
        x: "Amount",
        y: "Period"
      }
    },
    { // original erroneous outline
      type: "bar",
      colorBy: "data",
      label: {
        show: true,
      },
      labelLayout(params) {
        return {
          x: params.rect.x + 10,
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          align: "left"
        };
      },
      encode: {
        x: "Amount",
        y: "Period"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container'), null, {
  renderer: 'svg'
});
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="chart-container" style="height:400px; width: 80vw"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
```

The next snippet does the same, with the only difference that the chart background color is black:

```js
const data = [
  ["Amount", "Period"],
  [100000, "180+"],
  [80000, "61-90"],
  [70000, "31-60"],
  [60000, "0-30"]
];

const option = {
  backgroundColor: '#000',
  dataset: {
    source: data
  },
  color: ["#ff4242", "#FFA500", "#fddc20", "#209c05"],
  xAxis: {
    name: "Amount",
  },
  yAxis: {
    name: "Period",
    type: "category"
  },
  series: [{ // solution 1: replace x by dx
      type: "bar",
      colorBy: "data",
      label: {
        show: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      },
      labelLayout(params) {
        return {
          dx: -params.rect.width / 2 + 10,
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          align: "left"
        };
      },
      encode: {
        x: "Amount",
        y: "Period"
      }
    },
    { // solution 2: backgroundColor: 'transparent'
      type: "bar",
      colorBy: "data",
      label: {
        show: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent'
        // or:
        // color: 'black'
      },
      labelLayout(params) {
        return {
          x: params.rect.x + 10,
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          align: "left"
        };
      },
      encode: {
        x: "Amount",
        y: "Period"
      }
    },
    { // original erroneous outline
      type: "bar",
      colorBy: "data",
      label: {
        show: true,
      },
      labelLayout(params) {
        return {
          x: params.rect.x + 10,
          verticalAlign: "middle",
          align: "left"
        };
      },
      encode: {
        x: "Amount",
        y: "Period"
      }
    }
  ]
};

const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart-container'), null, {
  renderer: 'canvas'
});
myChart.setOption(option);
```

```html
<div class="chart" id="chart-container" style="height:400px; width: 80vw"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js"></script>
```

One can see that the coloring of the labels in the first series (topmost bar in each group) makes a *best contrast to the color of the bar*, the second series has a fixed color, and the third  (the original one) the color is to ensure *the best contrast to the background color*

---

**Original post**

I think you somehow activated the shadow of the label text. That's not the default behavior, see [this echarts example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack).

So to get something like you have I had to set the `label` option as

```js
    label: {
        textShadowColor: 'white',
        textShadowOffsetX: 1,
        textShadowOffsetY: 1,
        textShadowBlur: 2,
        color: 'black',
        show: true
      }
```

[example fork](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-y-category-stack&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWszGAG0iAXMmuhgE4QDmFApqYQOQCGAHhAM70A0x6L7ACsAjQwtQqhIkA9FNgBVNtVh82GYGUo1SanHh4kwATxDUGbABaMAJsADu9WDNj0L1uw8aqr1AGaMArrgA3LAAxoxwjNhs6gBGSvTYwtQOwNouljb2-gC-xDnc6NjUNNBW4gXEFOTlRJLFPmAMAMwApFz65BTmTc4ALO2FJLHAYJgAti2D-qEwYIzCADKM8diEYKT-1PlDzACCrGzi-kYmDABuUVv0O8SGB-zHkqemzuGiFGmGHZJWjPOEADa9AAsjAuM4ACrXTjOADq1CsEPokPM_mRADFyMiAMr_XH-aD0AC6t3QinI1COsEB-gkklg0EY41e9AAIhBSNRQmAfgyXgxYoxSHzJGx5qEANYMTDzbCikjYFbUNZ1BnoUTMMA4zJ2ADCODSDFs5ggogVz2oWp1blsAHkfD5FGAABqEACMQ3Vmu1uvtjudAE0PV7-VbfbaAELYfx0WAAJlDklm2CNzliSqlFpIFjs60223VlXV1HGIEsbEeavVPmAoX81JctAgVJuRaTsD-AJpzXjAAZYc0-4nYEPPaPmn1BwBOAcTue9vukyTFkj0yRMlkMEELbCwPZIjsC9PC7PixhSmWjKLZpWrJ7q2C52z5rb6dCrySl8ueKvrhm1vWjYUi2HDvrAn4kF2jBAu6_awu6vYIX246IVOsCzrC8ZDlh7pLrkob_ugm6snsjoQEk_xKAe2bHvQQoih256Xs4so3h2d4qg-6rPq-hYMpB6DfhWf7geggENmYzatuBgmdv8ME0vG8GwO6AAcI7utO47Yeh8aYfOg54cuJCQURjLMqyABqEDeOoNFHsYrIMWeErSqx17yhxyqquZ5LmHmZBvu24HCb-1J-bAEnAdJYEheq0GwQArHO8ZwVhKEIUl6FaQuOGwH0xkEXS4EkQwOLUMKoTmLAACi0AUMktFOYKp5MW5V5yrePncQyvFBfxK4dmFlYRWJUV1pJzggTJ8UMolNIaXOalIRhmUYZOCH6XOiH5Yh_YmR-xCkjkQRAA) - first series

So to cancel it, I expect you may set any of

```js
   label: {
        textShadowColor: 'transparent', // or
        textShadowOffsetX: 0,  textShadowOffsetY: 0, // or
        textShadowBlur: 0,
   }
```

Please let me know if that doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks @kikon. I am not adjusting the shadow text to my knowledge. I've updated the post with the full options object being loaded.

Comment: With the code, I was able to reproduce the problem in react with `echarts-for-react`; it's not the text shadow; I'll look into it to see how can you disable it.

Comment: It appears to be the result of the use of `labelLayout`, although there is no reasonable connection. A simple fix is to disable `x` and `y` in `labelLayout` result and set `dx: -params.rect.width / 2 + 10`, see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-taussig-9vhc5t?file=/src/App.js). I'll look later today to understand what's happening and how can one set `x` and `y` without getting the white outline, and I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thank you @kikon! I will likely go with the first option. Should I report this to Echarts as a bug??

Comment: It's not really a bug, if you consider for instance the case when a label is half inside and half outside. I'll think in the following days about filling a  feature request - there should be a way to request inside type colors.

Comment: But I have to look if there isn't one already :) I thought that could be achieved by setting `label.position: 'inside'` [doc ref](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label.position), but it's superseded by the `layout`. I'll let you know here if I find out something new.

Comment: Thank you for this thread! Great answser @kikon! However, I can't see why not being able to adjust the drop-shadow options isn't a bug (or a valuable enhancement request): if you go to the theme builder on the official web site and look at the labels of the pie chart on any dark theme, you will notice this (ugly IMHO) drop shadow. Shouldn't I still open an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Thanks @YannVo; in the post I said that it's a bug or at least a missing feature; in comments I said that one has to be careful about it since when the label is half inside half outside it's not a bug (I should've said, it's just half a bug  :) ). I never posted a bug report, so you're welcome to do that if you have time and think it's useful.

Comment: @kikon => https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19404
My pleasure! 